# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - How to keep track of historical email addresses tied to one subscriber?

Tags: marketing-cloud

So, the problem in a nutshell is I need to be able to keep track of when subscribers change their email addresses and tie them all back to the single subscriber.

Here's what I did - I set the Subscriber Key value to be a numeric identifier.  I then created a data extension and I set ID as the Subscriber Key.  I imported a sample data file with ID of 62078213 tied to mmarks@salesforce.com.  I sent myself an email and then clicked Profile Center, and changed my email address.

Here's what happened.  Before I made my change, I checked _Subscribers and found my record that was newly added from the email send.  Awesome.  Okay, then I updated my email address to mike@mikemarks.net from the stock preference center.  I then checked _Subscribers again:

```
select * from Cxxxxxxx._Subscribers with (nolock) where ID = 62078213
```

Running this query brought back the UPDATED record in _Subscribers - which had email address as the updated mike@mikemarks.net email address.  Further, I did

```
select * from Cxxxxxxxx._Subscribers with (nolock) where EmailAddress = 'mmarks@salesforce.com'
```

Recall, this was the ORIGINAL email address that was sent the email.

No results.  So, I don't know where the "historical" email addresses are stored, or if they even are - several people I've talked to mentioned that this is the way to go about it if you want to tie a subscriber back to multiple email addresses.  I wonder if there's a business rule that needs to be turned on.  Any insight would be terrific, if you know of anything I'm missing.

Comment: I don't think there is any out of the box way to do this. As soon as you change the email address, all the tracking data gets tied to the new address.

Comment: Well if I'm not mistaken @ManeeshGupta I think tracking data is tied to the subscriber key, is it not?

Comment: Yes it is and that is why you cannot get the historical email address from tracking data. It doesn't make sense to me although. If I had sent an email to my yahoo Address then I should always be able to see that yahoo address in my tracking data (regardless of what my current email address is)

Answer (score 1):

Historical email addresses are not stored by default.  If there is a reason that this information is needed then a SendLog might be a good option as that will log the value used at send-time to a data extension.  This data extension can then be queried to find the different addresses that were sent to for a given subscriber but wouldn't catch if they updated their email address between sends.

Send Logging:
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/